# Guest users cannot create cases in our community

Tags: community, case, web2case

We would like guest (non-logged in) users to be able to create cases, but despite following the steps in [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_guest_users.htm&type=5), they're still unable to do so. I've done the following:

- enabled **web-to-case**
- enabled **Guest Access to the Support API**
- added a custom quick action to the **Selected Quick Actions** menu; NewCase also failed
- ensured that the correct record type is assigned to **record type settings** under the guest's profile
- provided the guest user with **read** and **create** case object permissions
- made our **contact support community page** public

Despite all of this, whenever I try to access the contact support page as a guest user, I'm always re-directed to our login page.

*I've run out of troubleshooting ideas and would appreciate this community's help!*

Comment: is it a lightning community?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at  [Case Records Not Getting Created by Guest Users in Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Case-Records-Not-Getting-Created-by-Unauthenticated-Guests-in-Communities&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: @glls -- Yeah, it's a Lightning community.

Comment: @codeyinthecloud -- I gave edit permissions in the article you shared, but no luck. Note the issue is guest users cannot even access the case submission form.

Answer (score 3):

So my co-worker and I found the issue. Here's the path:

**Case submission form** > **Actions in the Publisher** > **Guest User Case Action**

The issue was that there was nothing tethered to the Guest User Case Action. When we tied it to an action, the form displayed. :-)

Comment: being redirected to the login and the form not displaying are 2 completely different behaviors, =/

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make sense to me either. It still seems to work, though.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ . In any case, good thing you got it wor work

Answer (score 0):

> Despite all of this, whenever I try to access the contact support page
>   as a guest user, I'm always re-directed to our login page

Some other things you might want to valdiate:

- Public can access the community is checked? (assuming it is)
- Community is Published & Active?
- Can guests accecss the home page without having to log in?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes :-) 

A co-worker just followed the Trailhead guide on this in a new sandbox and it works. So I'm thinking there's a configuration in our existing sandbox/production that's responsible for this hurdle.

Comment: In theory, the contact support page should be available once the above is done

Comment: @orbuculum are there any custom components forcing a redirection/login ?

Comment: No, all of our components are out-of-the-box.